# Transformation Best Practices on using DynamoDb Data Modeling

Tags: java

I am creating a web project where I retrieve records from my database - AWS DynamoDb. I desire to have an abstraction layer in case the database provider needs to change.

This is the pattern I am commonly following. The model class, the dynamo db model class and a transformer class.

```
public record Student (String id, String firstName, String lastName, String email) { }

@DynamoDBTable(tableName = “MyTable)
@Data
public class StudentRecord {
    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName="pk")
    private String pk;
    @DynamoDBRangeKey(attributeName="sk")
    private String sk;
    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName="firstName")
    private String firstName;
    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName="lastName")
    private String lastName;
    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName="email")
    private String email;
}


public class StudentRecordTransform implements RecordTransform<StudentRecord, Student> {
    @Override
    public Student transform(StudentRecord entity) {
        Student model = new Student(entity.getUsername(), entity.getFirstName(), entity.getLastName(), entity.getEmail());
        return model;
    }

    @Override
    public StudentRecord untransform(Student model) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

It may feel verbose and tedious just to create a new record type into the database. Is this consider a good best practice? I am looking forward a code review on this.